# Why can't I determine what this Point value is?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In the stub below spc is a StylusPointCollection, i = 3 (or anything greater) and spc.Count = 1024

```
for (Int32 i = 0, i < spc.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(spc[i].X.ToString() + " : " + spc[i].Y.ToString());
    ...
```

The error message information is:

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.dll
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: X
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ...

I can't find any way of analysing X to see what it is and so what is going wrong.  I have tried things like IsNaN and IsInfinity but the same error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like there actually is not a value for X at that specific value of i. If you attach the debugger & break on your Debug line you should look into the spc collection & examine some of the failing indexes, then look at your inputs.